Does $\sum_{i\neq j}^{\infty}(-1)^{i+j}\;\frac{\cos\left(q\:\log\frac{i}{j}\right)}{(ij)^p}$ converge for $0<p<1$ and $q\in\mathbb{R}$?
I was looking into some number theory and I came across the summation here given as:
$$\sum_{i\neq j}^{\infty}(-1)^{i+j}\;\frac{\cos\left(q\:\log\frac{i}{j}\right)}{(ij)^p}$$
when I was thinking of a hypothetical problem about off diagonal sums that I don't believe can be easily solved by what I learned so far.
I was essentially wondering if this sum converges or diverges for $0<p<1$ and $q\in\mathbb{R}$, or if there is a mixture of convergence and divergence within this interval? We also assume that $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$. I am curious to finding out if this sum actually diverges or converges, because there seem to be signs that it should converge and signs that it should diverge. What I have gotten so far for an argument for it converging is that the fraction on the right decays as $i$ and $j$ get larger and so by the alternating series test, it appears this should converge. However, the $cos(q\:log(\frac{i}{j}))$ term seems to oscillate unpredictably between being positive and being negative, so in effect, it might cancel out enough of the $(-1)^{i+j}$ term and by the p-series test, this sum might actually diverge. Anyways, I was wondering if anyone here can provide insights on this problem?
If you come to an answer, please show how you justify your conclusion. Any help would be much appreciated as I am relatively new to learning pure mathematics!
EDIT: I recently found a solution to this problem myself.

Hello and welcome to Math.SE. Please add more information about your question, e.g. where the question comes from, why you are asking, what you have done so far / what your ideas and thoughts are behind it. Please also choose a title that uniquely addresses your problem (not such a generic title). Currently the question is of the form "This is my problem. Solve it." and that doesn't meet the site's guidelines.

Hi there! Thank you for notifying me about this. It has been fixed.
